# Regex find text between complex tags C#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a string like `<p style="color: #323232;">Text</p>`, where I want to strip away the tags using Regular Expressions so I am just left with the string "Text".

The Regex pattern I am trying is `<p (.*?)<\/p>`, but this returns `style="color: #323232;">Text`. I won't always know the exact parameters used within the `<p>` tag so I can't just change the Regex pattern to include that. Basically I need to change the Regex pattern so it will search for "`<p` " followed by anything until it hits "`>`", but I'm not sure how to do this.

I would appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html

Comment: I've closed this question because it's a classic mistake to think that you can parse HTML with Regex. It just won't work out for you. Read the answers of the linked question, then start to think about other, more reliable ways that you might be able to get the data you want. There's a good hint in the first comment.

Comment: HTML is not a regular language, so don't use regular expressions.  Use the HTMLAgilityPack or equivalent library to parse HTML.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/47589

Comment: If you don't have `>` in an attribute value and no nested `<p>`s inside, try `<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>`